# Inheritance: memory address of fields

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

If I have two classes

```
class A {
  int n;
  void doSomething() {
    n = 2;
  }
}
```

and

```
class B extends A {}
```

Is the memory address of `this.n` the same as of `super.n` when called in B?
Also, would `this.doSomething()` and `super.doSomething()` modify the same `n` in memory?

Comment: Yes, it's the same.

Comment: Is that also the case in C++?

Comment: I have never worked on c++, but it should be same.

Comment: @SandeepKumar - That's a dangerous assumption across languages I'd recommend not making. (It **may** be true in this case...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the memory address of `this.n` the same as of `super.n` when called in `B`?

Yes. But in Java, you basically don't usually need to care where things are in memory. :-) (Which is good, because you *can't* get the memory address of something, and in fact the JVM may even change the address of something over time...)

> Also, would `this.doSomething()` and `super.doSomething()` modify the same `n` in memory?

Yes, there is only **one** `n` in the instance in your example.

---

It *is* possible to have more than one `n`, if two classes in the hierarchy both declare `n` fields, but usually you don't care because either:

1. They're both/all declared `private`, and so the code just works because each code modifying `n` modifies the right one; or
2. They aren't declared private, in which case it's poor practice and confusing to have more than one field called `n`. :-)

Here's an example of #1:

```
class Base {
    private int n;

    public Base(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return this.n;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    private int n;

    public Derived(int n) {
        super(n / 2);
        this.n = n;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return this.n;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("this.getN()  = " + this.getN());
        System.out.println("super.getN() = " + super.getN());
    }
}
```

There are two separate `n` fields, one for `Base` and one for `Derived`, but they're both private so it's not confusing (well, mostly not). If you run

```
Derived d = new Derived(42);
d.show();
```

you'll get

```
this.getN()  = 42
super.getN() = 21
```

Here's an example of #2, which, again, is poor practice:

```
class Base {
    protected int n;

    public Base(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    protected int n; // POOR PRACTICE, don't do this

    public Derived(int n) {
        super(n / 2);
        this.n = n;
    }

    public void show() {
        System.out.println("this.n  = " + this.n);
        System.out.println("super.n = " + super.n);
    }
}
```

If you run

```
Derived d = new Derived(42);
d.show();
```

you get

```
this.n  = 42
super.n = 21
```